# How can I change all values of an array list in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I change the values in an arraylist with names from:

```
christopher hitchens
william craig
```

to

```
hitchens, christopher
craig, william
```

Comment: @mata :java, mentioned in the question...

Comment: did you try anything...post your code

Comment: You write the code that changes one value, then you write the code that iterates over the array, then you put the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split` to split the first and last name, and then you can put them together again in any order you want:

```
List<String> nameList = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); ++i) {
    String[] names = nameList.split(" ");
    nameList.set (i, names[1] + ", " + names[0]);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  The questioner also wants the order of the surname and forename swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, you can do it the following:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
listOfStrings.add("christopher hitchens");
listOfStrings.add("william craig");
listOfStrings.forEach(this::mapper);
```

And as `mapper()`:

```
private String mapper(final String input) {
    String[] parts = input.split(" ");
    return parts[1] + ", " + parts[0];
}
```

If you want to handle more cases, then you will need to provide a better `mapping()` method, I made a very naïve version based on your input/output example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [java8](/questions/tagged/java8) you could look at the [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("christopher hitchens","william craig");
list.replaceAll(s -> {String[] names = s.split(" "); 
                      return names[1]+","+names[0];}
                );
```

Comment: If I would use a lambda to save some code and space, I wouldn't explicitely write a `StringBuilder` as the compiler will do that for me. We're trying to write readable code here, aren't we?